# How do I tell somebody to "get to work"?

Tags: english-to-german

Does "get to work" (imperative) translate directly, or is there another way of saying this?

Comment: It depends on how your relationship to "somebody" is.

Comment: Agree with René Nyffenegger; there are a lot of informal alternatives ;)

Answer (score 8):

You could say "an die Arbeit!". This however does not include any information about *who* has to get to work: It can mean "get to work" and "let us all get to work".

Answer (score 1):

An informal way to express that an immediate action is asked from an imperative would be adding "*auf*" or "*los*":

> *"Auf, an die Arbeit!"* - *"Los, ans Werk!"*